# How to remove tubes from co2 regulators

Tags: beer, co2, kegerator, tubing

This has been a long pain to remove tubes from CO2 regulators.

To install the Kegerators for event we use C02 cylinder and regulators. After event to dismantle everything we always face issues related to removing that red tube from regulators.

Is anyone has an easy way to remove it? [image]

Comment: 4-equally-spaced box-cutter incisions, lengthwise, along the metal ribbing, often gets the process moving along nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had pretty good luck removing stuck hose with a heat gun or a hair dryer.  Another option to consider is convert to a [Duotight gas fitting](https://www.morebeer.com/products/duotight-pushin-fitting-8-mm-516-14-flare.html) and use a [removal tool](https://www.homefermenter.com/products/duotight-removal-tool-and-tube-cutter) to simply detach the hose.